# Xamarin Forms wait for animation or event to finish

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So i'm trying to make my button perform its animation before another action happens. But its kind of weird how i have it set up.

I have a subclassed button called AnimatedButton that adds a Click += AnimatedButton_Clicked handler that does the animations, as seen below:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TransactionApp_2.Views.UITools.Buttons
{
    class AnimatedButton : Button
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Generic Animated Button Subclass that allows for:
        /// Button indexing,
        /// Simple sleek animations,
        /// Sets initial properties and parameters,
        /// allows easy background images
        /// </summary>

        public int ButtonIndex { get; set; }
        public AnimatedButton(string buttonText, ImageSource backgroundImage = null, int buttonIndex = 0)
        {
            ButtonIndex = buttonIndex;
            Text = buttonText;
            FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label));
            Opacity = 0.95;
            Margin = new Thickness(8,0,8,0);

            Clicked += AnimatedButton_Clicked;

            if (backgroundImage != null)
            {
                //Set Background Image
            }

        }
        private async void AnimatedButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //Obsolete version of OnPlatform
#pragma warning disable CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete
            var platformSpecific = Device.OnPlatform<uint>(50, 50, 25); //Whats the new version of this??
#pragma warning restore CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete

            //Simple Animations
            await this.ScaleTo(0.85, platformSpecific, Easing.SinIn);


     await this.FadeTo(0.8, platformSpecific, Easing.SinOut);
        await this.FadeTo(0.95, platformSpecific, Easing.SinIn);
        await this.ScaleTo(1, platformSpecific, Easing.SinOut);
    }
}
```

}

In my UI backend code I also add a new clicked event that refreshes the grid of the UI as seen below:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {

            grid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowCollection[i]);
            AnimatedButton button = new AnimatedButton(menuOptions.ItemDataList[i].TitleText) { ButtonIndex = i+1};
            button.Clicked += (s, e) =>
            {
                        RefreshGrid(button.ButtonIndex);
            };
            grid.Children.Add(button, 0, i + 1);
        }
```

Obviously the two events are both executed at the same exact time when the button is pressed, the grid is refreshed before the animation finishes. Using this type of set up how can I make the RefreshGrid() call wait until the animation in the subclass is finished? I've been trying to use threading to handle this issue but no luck.

Thinking maybe there was a way to wait on the event or the animation to finish before the RefreshGrid() was called, or use Threading better.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you not have a boolean `performingAnimation` that is set to `false` by default, then set to `true` within your `AnimatedButton_Clicked` method, and once complete (ie. have an event) set it to `false`, and your Click handler on your form checks if this is still going? ie. `do until performingAnimation = false`? Would need to also ensure you don't run into an infinite loop there. Just a thought.

Comment: I tried that and it did not work at all. It was my first thought too. I'll try it again tonight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add delay as much as your animation.

```
await grid1.TranslateTo(-100, 0, 300);
await Task.Delay(300);
```

Comment: Better use a `TaskCompletionSource` and set its result in the finished callback.

Answer (score 2):

This may see like a work around but you can expose another event that is raised after the click event's animations are completed and let back end subscribe to that.

Roughly it could look like this. (DISCLAIMER: this code has not been tested.)

AnimatedButton:

```
public event EventHandler ClickedAnimationCompleted = delegate { };

private async void AnimatedButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    //...other code removed for brevity

    //Simple Animations
    await this.ScaleTo(0.85, platformSpecific, Easing.SinIn);

    await this.FadeTo(0.8, platformSpecific, Easing.SinOut);
    await this.FadeTo(0.95, platformSpecific, Easing.SinIn);
    await this.ScaleTo(1, platformSpecific, Easing.SinOut);

    ClickedAnimationCompleted(this, EventArgs.Empty);   
}
```

Back-end:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    grid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowCollection[i]);
    AnimatedButton button = new AnimatedButton(menuOptions.ItemDataList[i].TitleText) { ButtonIndex = i+1};
    button.ClickedAnimationCompleted += (s, e) => {
        RefreshGrid(button.ButtonIndex);
    };
    grid.Children.Add(button, 0, i + 1);
}
```